# Openlayers 3 Wicket add new feature after initialize

Tags: spring, apache, wicket, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm trying to add a new Feature with LineStrings whenever a button is clicked(after initialize), and I'm wondering how to do this without doing a refresh. Currently, when the button is clicked, the new Feature is added to map, but is not shown before I do a refresh of the page. What is the proper or easiest way to do this. The button I'm using is an AjaxButton, that not refreshes the page as I dont want it to be refreshed. My current solution is simply to `remove(this.map)` and then `add(this.map)` as this will load in the new map with the new Feature on the next refresh, but yeah, I want this to happend without needing the refresh.

Comment: Does that solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997633/openlayers-3-force-a-map-refresh

Answer (score 0):

`OpenLayersMap` has `#update(AjaxRequestTarget)` method for this.

```
AjaxButton button = new AjaxButton("someId") {

  @Override protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
     // add feature
     map.update(target); // this will repaint just the map
  }
```

}

Comment: Doesn't seem like map has an update function. Here is the class for it: http://wicketstuff.org/core/javadoc6/apidocs/org/wicketstuff/openlayers3/DefaultOpenLayersMap.html

Comment: And here is the source code: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/1fa257603ed918d54a32f0e92bd949aa86afb65c/openlayers-parent/openlayers/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/openlayers/OpenLayersMap.java#L835 (this is master branch from today).

Comment: OK. I see the difference. I looked at openlayers project, while you use openlayers3. It has `updateLayers()`: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/master/openlayers3-parent/openlayers3/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/openlayers3/OpenLayersMap.java#L379

Comment: Hmm. This didn't do anything. I added the new layer into map, and called map.updateLayers, and nothing happened. If i refresh afterwards, the new layer is there tho.

Comment: It looks like this function only iterates trough each layer and call `.setVisible` and `.setOpacity` on it. I don't think this will push the new feature's javascript up to the browser (?)